# Make a Javascript object available globally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know how to make a JavaScript object globally available.

I have an Angular service, from which I need an access to a public API key stored as an environment variable. My plan was to make a javascript declaration at the top of the `<body>` like this:

```
<script>
  MySite.settings = {
    PublishableKey = [here I retreive the env variable]      
  }
</script>
```

And inside the Angular service, I thought I could access that value by doing:

```
...
key: MySite.settings.PublishableKey
...
```

But I get an error that `MySite` is not defined.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you don't actually define `MySite`, just a property of it. Try this, instead:

```
<script>
    var MySite = {
        settings : {
            PublishableKey : 'some_key'
        }
    };
</script>
```

Notice that I used `:` instead of `=` to set the properties; that's the correct syntax here.

Comment: This worked. Why are you using `=` after `MySite`, but using `:` after `settings`? Isn't `settings` a property of `MySite`, and we need to use `:` to set properties?

Comment: @MikeC with `MySite =`, I am setting a variable. With `{foo : 'bar'}`, I am initializing a property. The two simply use different syntax. By the way, please remember to accept this as the answer! :)

Comment: Thank you. Learned something new.

Comment: You'll get an upvote from me if you change this to an explicitly defined global.